# Using flow with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm new to flow, and I don't succeed to use it correctly with react-native. I don't understand how I'm supposed to load RN types.
For instance, I'm trying to type a function that will return `nativeEvent.layout` which is of type `LayoutRectangle`.

I tried : `import * as RN from 'react-native';`

But using it as is gives me `Cannot resolve name LayoutRectangle` and `RN.LayoutRectangle` gives me : `Cannot get RN.LayoutRectangle because property LayoutRectangle is missing in module react-native [1]`

Here is a sample component that I'm trying to make.

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import * as RN from 'react-native';

type CompReference = {
  getLocation?: () => LayoutRectangle,
}
type Ref<T> = {
  current: null | T
}
type Props = {
  value: string
}

function CompFunction({value = ''}: Props = {}, ref: CompReference & Ref<HTMLElement> = {}) {
    const location: LayoutRectangle = React.useRef(null);
    ref.getLocation = () => location.current || { height: 0, width: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };
    return (<RN.Text onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => location.current = nativeEvent.layout}>{value}</RN.Text>);
}

const Comp = React.forwardRef<Props, CompReference & Ref<HTMLElement>>(CompFunction);
Comp.displayName = 'Comp';

export default Comp;
```

I also get an error about the forwardRef:

```
Cannot call `React.forwardRef` with `CompFunction` bound to `render` because property `current` is missing in function type [1] but exists in `Ref` [2] in the second argument. (index.js:34:76)flow
Cannot call `React.forwardRef` with `LetterFunction` bound to `render` because property `getLocation` is missing in object type [1] but exists in `CompReference` [2] in the second argument. (index.js:34:76)flow
Cannot call `React.forwardRef` with `CompFunction` bound to `render` because property `getLocation` is missing in statics of function type [1] but exists in `CompReference` [2] in the second argument. (index.js:34:76)flow
Cannot call `React.forwardRef` with `CompFunction` bound to `render` because property `current` is missing in `HTMLElement` [1] but exists in `Ref` [2] in property `current` of the second argument. (index.js:34:76)flow
Cannot call `React.forwardRef` with `CompFunction` bound to `render` because in property `current` of the second argument: Either `CompReference` [1] is incompatible with `HTMLElement` [2]. Or `Ref` [3] is incompatible with `HTMLElement` [2]. (index.js:34:76)flow
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Flow, you need to import the types.

So you need to add something like

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import * as RN from 'react-native';
import type {LayoutRectangle} from 'CoreEventTypes'; //Or wherever your type LayoutRectangle is defined
```

<sub>Note that I might not have the same RN version than you as `nativeEvent.layout` is of type `Layout` in my version which doesn't have a `current` property.</sub>

Note : if the type is not exported anywhere, you could use :

```
import typeof {LayoutRectangle} from 'react-native';
```

Source : https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#importing-and-exporting-types-

Comment: If you pay a close look, `nativeEvent.layout` doesn't need a `current` field in my code. This is just the use of `useRef` React hook that might give this feeling.

Comment: What is "CoreEventTypes"? Moreover, I don't understand because when I hover `nativeEvent.layout` in VSCode, flow tells me that it is of type `RN.LayoutRectangle`. So where did it get this information, and why is it unable to access it within the file?

Comment: @Sharcoux You must have an `export type LayoutRectangle` in one your files, and you have to import the type. VSCode correctly find the type, but to use Flow in your file you need to import the types that you are using. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I could do it with `import type { Layout } from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CoreEventTypes';`. I have no idea where this `LayoutRectangle` came from. I'm still unable to use flow due to the error with forwardRef, though...

Comment: You also need to import the types `HTMLElement` and `LetterReference`, maybe that will fix your issue.
By the way, no need to create your own `Ref` type, just use Maybe type : https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/

Comment: Apparently, `HTMLElement` is already imported, but I don't know how exactly. Maybe it is thanks to the installation of flow-typed. About `LetterReference`, I fixed it in my question, it was supposed to be `CompReference`. My bad. The issue remains.